# iOS draw borderline for part of a view

Tags: ios, border

Tried to search similar questions, but no success.

In this iOS app, I have a big square subview, which I dissect into four small ones, let me call them smallA, smallB, smallC, and smallD, and the big subview BigS. I draw borderline for bigS at the beginning. Later, smallB will disappear and the subview holds only smallA/C/D. I now need re-draw the borderline, which needs surround small A/C/D only, but not B. How do I draw it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it just a border pattern , not the border property.

I think you shold override the `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method of the `BigS`, and the `Bigs` shuold have this property `drawingBeginPoint`,`drawingWidth`,`drawingHeight`,and before you `setNeedsDisplay`you should set the 3 properties of `BigS`, the `Bigs` can calc the path through the 3 properties in the drawRect , and then you can use `Core Graphics` to draw the "border"

Comment: thanks. I thought there would be a quick and easy way.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I will subclass the `UIView` and draw the border manually in the subclass's `drawRect`. Because the default border can't do this for you. Your bigS is not a regular rectangle. You can refer to this tutorial:[Core Graphics 101: Lines, Rectangles, and Gradients](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2033/core-graphics-101-lines-rectangles-and-gradients)